How to decalre multiprocess pool as a variable and import it to another python file
I have two python files.
File: multiprocess_pool.py

from multiprocessing import Pool

A = Pool(5)

File: main.py
from multiprocess_pool import A

def start(x):
    print(x+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with A as a:
        print(a.apply_async(start, args=(1,)).get())

When I exectue python main.py, I get the next error.
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'start' on <module '__main__' 

I don’t want to declare the Pool in main.py. Since my service is a web server, I need to call Pool to perform some CPU-intensive tasks. I’d like to declare Pool as a variable and import it into another file.

What concrete benefit are you hoping to get by putting the creation of A in a separate file? I suspect you're expecting that to do something it doesn't.

I want to use the process pool like the thread pool in Java. When my service (web server) receive a request, in my response thread(I use async io, so there is only one thread), I will use the processPool to do some task. I don't think It is right to declare and destory the process pool for each request.

So what you really need to do is create and store the pool somewhere that lives longer than a single request, and putting it in its own module is the approach you came up with to do that?

Yes, I need to reuse the pool. So I think i can declare the pool as class instance variable like java threadpool.

You can indeed just make it an instance variable. That would be a reasonable way to do things, and it would avoid the issue you're currently having. I'm surprised you didn't already just go with that.

(Well, it'd avoid the initialization issues causing your current problem. You still might have issues with how you handle shutdown.)

I think i can declare it as class instance variable and then implement the del method。 But the real question is I can’t run the code if i dont declare pool at main python py

If you want to avoid needing to use __main__, or files at all, you can use multiprocess. It's a fork of multiprocessing that has better serialization but otherwise the same interface.
>>> import multiprocess
>>> def start(x):
...   print(x)
...   return x+1
... 
>>> with multiprocess.Pool(4) as pool:
...   print(pool.apply_async(start, args=(1,)).get())
... 
1
2

If you want to create a persistent Pool instance that can easily be shut down and restarted, you might try pathos, which is mostly a wrapper around multiprocess to (1) provide a map interface that is the same as python's builtin serial map, and (2) to provide more persistent Pool objects.
>>> import pathos
>>> pool = pathos.pools.ProcessPool(4)
>>> print(pool.apipe(start, 1).get())
1
2
>>> pool.close()
>>> pool.join()
>>> 
>>> pool.restart()
<multiprocess.pool.Pool state=RUN pool_size=4>
>>> print(pool.apipe(start, 1).get())
1
2


It is critical that you only start the Pool on the main thread. All sorts of bad things happen if the creation of the pool happens outside of if __name__ == "__main__" or outside a function that is only called from there.
You really want:
def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as pool:
         pool.apply_async(....)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Note also that in general, that
x = <calculate x>
with x:
    .....

does not necessarily do the same thing as
with <calculate x> as x:
    ....

This may happen to work for pools, but it is a bad habit to get into.  Don't do it. Almost always you want with <expression> as variable:

If i write with Pool(x) as p, I think it will create and destory the pool one time. If i want to reuse the Pool (Because my service is a web server.) How should I do that ?
Moreover, You say that can only start Pool from the main thread. Whether can I declare the Pool instance at another python file , then import it to main python py and start it.

@themonkeyofBIT: The way you've written things, if your code worked, it'd still shut down and destroy the pool as soon as the with statement ends. That's the point of using a with statement.

You need to restructure your code as follows. This ensures that your Pool instance is constructed in the main program:
def start(x):
    print(x)
    return x+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocess_pool import A
    with A:
        print(A.apply_async(start, args=(1,)).get())

Output:
1
2

